# Why mongoose schema created with schema stored in variable won't see required flag?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

If I store mongoose schema description object in the variable before creating new schema, it won't pick up proper schema options. For example:

```
const person = {
  name: { type: String, required: true }
};

const PersonSchema = new Schema(person);

type Person = InferSchemaType<typeof PersonSchema>;
```

`Person` type is now:

```
type Person = {
  name?: string;
}
```

Incorrectly marking `name` field as optional.

But when I do seemingly almost exact same thing:

```
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
});

type Person = InferSchemaType<typeof PersonSchema>;
```

`Person` type is now:

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
}
```

Correctly having `name` marked as required.

I really have no idea why this is the case.

Anyone can explain? Thanks!

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-cdn-kx378p?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just answered myself after bit more fiddling around.

It's more of a typescript thing rather than mongoose.

It's basically happening because if I define my object like this:

```
const person = {
  name: { type: String, required: true }
};
```

The object is still mutable so typescript won't assume `person.name` is of any value and therefore `name` becomes `string | undefined` essentially making this prop optional.

The solution is to tell typescript compiler, that this object won't change by adding `as const`.

This will work fine:

```
const person = {
  name: { type: String, required: true }
} as const;

const PersonSchema = new Schema(person);

type Person = InferSchemaType<typeof PersonSchema>;
```

Results in:

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
}
```